# lua function name for each string

Tags: function, lua

so im trying to add a function for each pair fx i have tried everything i could think of i have looked and looked for a way

i tried `lua _G[tes](arg1, arg2)` some said that it should do it couldn't get it to work like that i tried `lua loadstring` -/-

```lua
test = {
  "jhon",
  "bob",
  "mike"
}

for nr, name in pairs(test) do
  _G[name] = function ()
    print("I'm "..name)
  end
end

local run = math.random(1,3)

for nr, name in pairs(test) do
  if run == nr then
    name()
  end
end
```

Comment: when you ar trying to lern a new site ....









then next question how do i trigger it fx like this 

```lua
test = { */
    "jhon", */
    "bob", */
    "mike" */
} */
*/
for nr, name in pairs(test) do */
    _G[name] = function () */
        print("I'm "..name) */
    end */
end */
*/
local run = math.random(1,3) */
 */
for nr, name in pairs(test) do */
    if run == nr then */
        name() */
    end */
end */
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

got it working for what i wanted like this thx you 2 for the help and info

```lua
test = {
  "jhon",
  "bob",
  "mike",
  "ELF0001"
}

local run = 4

-------------------------------

for nr, name in pairs(test) do
  _G[name .. "r"] = function ()
    print("I'm Not "..name)
  end
end

for nr, name in pairs(test) do
  _G[name .. "a"] = function ()
    print("I'm "..name)
  end
end

--------------------------------

for nr, name in pairs(test) do
  if run ~= nr then
    _G[name .. "r"]()
  end
end

for nr, name in pairs(test) do
  if run == nr then
    _G[name .. "a"]()
  end
end
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
test = {
  "jhon",
  "bob"
}

for nr, name in pairs(test) do
  _G[name] = function ()
    print("I'm "..name)
  end
end

jhon()  --> I'm jhon
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a variable `tes` and define `local function tes()`, it will just overwrite the variable `tes`. More precisely, it will shadow it, but that really makes no difference here.

You can't declare local variables on the fly either, so that's out of the question; you can, hovewer, declare global variables, because they're not even real variables, but key-value-pairs in a table called the global environment.

In Lua 5.1 and earlier, you can access the global environment through the `_G` value; in Lua 5.2 and above you can also use the `_ENV` variable instead, but `_G` still works for your purpose.

To add a new "global" variable, you can simply index this table and add a new key-value-pair to it:

```
for _, letter in ipairs {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'} do
  _G[letter] = function() print(letter) end
end

a() --> prints "a"
b() --> prints "b"
-- etc.
```

What you have to remember is this though:

```
local name = 'John'
local tab = {}

-- These are all equivalent:
tab[name] = 'Doe' -- Gets the actual contents of name, which is 'John'
tab['John'] = 'Doe'
tab.John = 'Doe'
-- After any of those, tab looks like this: {John = 'Doe'}
-- (Which is the same as {['John'] = 'doe'})

-- This one is different though:
tab.name = 'Doe'
-- After this, tab looks like this: {name = 'Doe'}
-- (Which is the same as{['name'] = 'Doe'} )
```

So if you have a variable `tes` which contains a string, you have to do

```
_G[tes] = function()
  -- Do stuff with tes
end
```